# Text Field with default placeholder and value that can't be delete

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want Text field with predefined value & placeholder and that can't be changed.

For example : Slack workspace. Where we can not edit `slack.com` but will have to write text before that.

So the placeholder be like 12345678.hello.com but when user try to enter value in that box then .hello.com should fixed but user can write before this text.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you have some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my try.
It is made by compositing with TextField and Text widgets. 
After receive a input by TextField, attach predefined value.

xxxxx(input value) + .slack.com(predefined value)

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 4),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            IntrinsicWidth(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: '12345678',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                autocorrect: false,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              '.slack.com',
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can also be achieved in this way.

```
TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "yourmail@slack.com",
                suffix: Text("@slack.com"),

                prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent),
              ),
          ),
```